# How can I make this pattern seamless in illustator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

Is there a way to make this pattern seamless? I can't seem to fill the negative space.

I'm trying to use the object-> pattern-> make, but might not be the best way. I'm more of a Photoshop user than Illustrator.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could step the pattern up so that the tile that you create for the pattern is 'full' when perpendicular / parallel to the document. You would need to step up your logo as follows and then group the four copies:
[image]

The blue highlighted object is a box with no fill and no stroke, this sits behind the other objects and defines the box for the pattern repeat. Select your grouped objects and the invisible box (which is not grouped with the other objects) and then make your pattern (or drag the whole lot to the swatches palette and you'll get the effect that you are looking for.

This method has the advantage of allowing more complex arrangements than just regular tiles, such as the following:
[image]

Comment: [No need](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/80204/52050)

Comment: Thanks Chris. You just answered my next question with this :)

Comment: @Cai Yeah, I quite like your answer (hence the up vote). I've edited mine to make it clear that is an alternative method. There are a few reasons why I tend to do it my way one of which I have now illustrated.

Answer (score 2):

Change the tile type to "Brick by Row" and reduce the height to pull each row in:

[image]

(any of the other "X by Y" options will do the trick too, with different dimension adjustments)

Comment: Well yes, or you could just you know model it in shape of the pattern square and then rotate the pattern.